# How can I optimize the color changes to resemble how objects look in the far distance?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, tools, plugin

I want to resemble how objects look in the far distance, so I need to shift the colors in the objects to some bluish tone where the farther the object the closer the color is to the one in the sky. At the moment I just copy the objects in the foreground, change the scale, remove a bit of saturation in HSB color space, and then change some values in RGB or CMYK color space moving the values closer to blue in the sky. This procedure is error prone and require multiple interactions, so I was wondering whether there is a plugin or a third party tool or something I can use to speed up the process.

For instance, in this case I change the blue component in RGB color space to the bluish side.

[image]

Some times it's no clear what direction to move the handles in RGB color space so I need to change to CMYK color space.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you already know how to do this, and you are happy with the results, you could create your own action?

Comment: @mayersdesign an action won't suffice, sometimes the color shift needs to be done in CMYK color space if it's not clear what direction should I move the handles toward, I attached some pictures with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the color of the object does not simulate the air in front of the object. Air is partially transparent blueish filter. Transparency is reduced by small particles. The blue color comes from the upper air where the short wavelength radiation makes the oxygen to glow. When the sun is down, red and orange pop up because the light travels very long path through the dusty lower air which blocks more shorter wavelengths.

You can simulate the air by a filled layer in PS and a filled object in Illustrator. The fill color hue, saturation and brightness depend on the local conditions. The opacity also depends on local conditions.

In the following example I took the fill color from the sky. I simulate the distance (=changing opacity) with a layer mask. The total effect strength is adjusted by changing the layer opacity. The first image is without the haze.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's pretty much it. One more thing, would the effect of using multiple bluish layers with the same opacity and color make those objects occluded by two layers look farther away than those occluded only by one layer?

Comment: @rraallvv Yes. 2 equivalent filtering layers affect like the doubling of the distance. This is not true, if we go over the horizon, because the further we go the higher is the visible altitude and the cleaner is the air, but there can be clouds, too.

Comment: Hmmm... for clouds I think I can move them to the foreground and poke a hole in them with the shape of those objects in other planes. I don't need the coulds to look too realistic.